# Ubuntu 20 lts - blank screen without suspension

Tags: gnome, 20.04, suspend, power-management, hibernate

My desktop PC with Ubuntu 20.04LTS needs to go blank screen after X minutes without suspension/hibernation. After upgradion to 20.04 I had some issues with disabling suspension and hibernation. Found solution to use this command:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

and that worked for me. My PC after launch is working 24/7 as expected. But 1 option that I wanted to stay isn't working, I mean blank screen after X minutes. In gnome settings blank screen is set to activate after 5 min but isn't working. How can I enable this option without enabling suspension/hibernation. This is the only option avaiable in gnome settings (in power tab) after using command above.
[Gnome option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd0N5.png)

Answer (score 1):

You might try these commands :

```
$ xset +dpms s on
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 300
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled true
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim true
```

Comment: Before using these commands do I have to revert previous changes? I mean, unmasking them by: sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

Comment: No, you don't need to.